# Cannot cat .pem file inline as -i option to ssh

Tags: shell, permissions, cat, file-descriptors, nixos

I am getting this error:

> Warning: Identity file /dev/fd/63 not accessible: Bad file descriptor.

when running this command:

```
ssh -Y 'root@ec2-54-xxx-94-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' -i <(cat << EOF
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAgbUQXIfIWtMJpYcTn5C+LStaL8NICo/0l1V33IQ8pQADUk+Tq+cfotyiHrRl  
JXRyn8KJe8zmAQs7uSR3drVdj2KNFhXnFsEbXYxjAS93ZutO1Z2eBvvKcp/W8AoOr7r2JtTXaGml
W18/0Fot83UcVRdqYI4CCv5hhYN7oGDYT94d8d0yFtuIhXf8IlkCgYEAkugROAktxuG1AgQ9KGP5
.........
a3ZAHHf5F2rn0oW0X5YNtEWqhGknYQkkiztqaWAPM4bAP7gpDIqYyqh81soqYHxxP9q2Ch634NPb
BMmdZb9hMb/PY9bJNKwZt/yO7W0yq1zzjXFIqhymGDqkc/E4/K+V+svsDIV8VtainrY=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF
)
nix-collect-garbage
```

I am just trying to run the 'nix-collect-garbage' command on the remote machine.

Perhaps the temporary file/fd has the wrong permissions? Is there a way to give i the right permissions?

I assume it's a permissions problem with the process substitution but not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: The `/dev/fd/63` of a proc subst is not a temporary file, but a pipe (either anonymous or named).

Comment: Does that `nix-collect-garbage` program need input from stdin? If not, you could just `ssh -ni /dev/stdin user@host nix-collect-garbage <<'EOT' ... EOT` without the `cat`. Of course, putting private keys in scripts is never a good idea, but when testing inconsequential stuff out it may turn out to be safer than having to manually create a temp file, then delete it, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh` will [close](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/5a273a33ca1410351cb484af7db7c13e8b4e8e4e/ssh.c#L616) all its file descriptors, except for the standard in, out and err, before doing anything interesting, even before parsing its command line switches.

So you cannot use process substitutions (or any shell features which are using the `/dev/fd/` mechanism) to pass file arguments to `-i` or other options.